# Add legend to ordirgl {vegan3d}

Tags: r, legend, rgl, vegan

I am trying to add a legend to a graphic produced using `ordirgl()` from the [vegan3d](/questions/tagged/vegan3d) package. I have been successful in doing this using `plot3d()` and `legend3d()`  in the [rgl](/questions/tagged/rgl) package. I prefer some of the functionality offered in [vegan3d](/questions/tagged/vegan3d), though, as I am working with ordinations and would prefer to use it if I am able to make a legend.

Using the [rgl](/questions/tagged/rgl) package:

```
data("dune.env")
data("dune")
sol <- metaMDS(dune, k = 3)

par3d(windowRect = c(100, 100, 612, 612))
with(sol, plot3d(points[,1], points[,2], points[,3], type = "s", col = rainbow(3)[as.numeric(dune.env$Use)]))
legend3d("topright", legend = unique(dune.env$Use), pch = 16, col = rainbow(3), inset = c(0.03))
```

Is it possible to add a legend to this?

```
ordirgl(sol, size = 4, col = rainbow(3)[as.numeric(dune.env$Use)])
orglspider(sol, dune.env$Use, col = rainbow(3), scaling = "sites")
orglellipse(sol, dune.env$Use, col = rainbow(3), kind = "se", conf = .95, scaling = "sites")
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Doesn't the same `legend3d` call produce the same legend here?  `bgplot3d` hard-codes a white background; is that the issue?

Comment: @user2554330 Yes, `legend3d` does work! I thought because it was from a different package that it would not. Thank you.

Comment: `vegan3d` uses `rgl` to do the plotting.